# Android empty editText is crashing my program

Tags: java, android

First time into Java and I'm trying to create a simple tips calculator for my coworkers at the restaurant I work for, but when I leave one of the editText fields empty the program crashes.

MainACtivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    totalTipsInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalTipsInput);
    waiter1Hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waiter1Hours);
    waiter2Hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waiter2Hours);
    waiter3Hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waiter3Hours);
    waiter4Hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waiter4Hours);

    tipsPerHourView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipsPerHourView);
    totalHoursView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalHoursView);
    barsCutView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barsCutView);

    waiter1Pay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.waiter1Pay);
    waiter2Pay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.waiter2Pay);
    waiter3Pay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.waiter3Pay);
    waiter4Pay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.waiter4Pay);
    taxDepositView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taxDepositView);

    Button calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
    calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            double totalTips = Double.parseDouble(totalTipsInput.getText().toString());

            double cWaiter1Hours = Double.parseDouble(waiter1Hours.getText().toString());
            double cWaiter2Hours = Double.parseDouble(waiter2Hours.getText().toString());
            double cWaiter3Hours = Double.parseDouble(waiter3Hours.getText().toString());
            double cWaiter4Hours = Double.parseDouble(waiter4Hours.getText().toString());

            double resultTotalHours = cWaiter1Hours + cWaiter2Hours + cWaiter3Hours + cWaiter4Hours;
            double resultBarsCut = (totalTips * 7) / 100;
            double resultTaxDeposit = resultTotalHours * 3;
            double resultTipsPerHour = (totalTips - resultBarsCut - resultTaxDeposit) / resultTotalHours;

            double resultWaiter1Pay = cWaiter1Hours * resultTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter2Pay = cWaiter2Hours * resultTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter3Pay = cWaiter3Hours * resultTipsPerHour;
            double resultWaiter4Pay = cWaiter4Hours * resultTipsPerHour;

            totalHoursView.setText(Double.toString(resultTotalHours));
            tipsPerHourView.setText(Double.toString(resultTipsPerHour));
            barsCutView.setText(Double.toString(resultBarsCut));

            waiter1Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter1Pay));
            waiter2Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter2Pay));
            waiter3Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter3Pay));
            waiter4Pay.setText(Double.toString(resultWaiter4Pay));

            taxDepositView.setText(Double.toString(resultTaxDeposit));


        }
    });
}
```

Tried to do something like this but got an error with .length():

```
                if (double totalTips = Double.parseDouble(totalTipsInput.getText().toString()).length() < 1 || totalTipsInput = null) {
                totalTips = 0
            } else {
                double totalTips = Double.parseDouble(totalTipsInput.getText().toString());
            }
```

Comment: You can do something like so: `String tmpStr = totalTipsInput.getText().toString(); double totalTips = (tmpStr.legnth() > 0)? Double.parseDouble(tmpStr) : 0.0;` Adapt this for your other fields.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble("")` exception on empty string ?

Comment: try some thing like `if(waiter1Hours.getText!=null)` 
               `double cWaiter1Hours = Double.parseDouble(waiter1Hours.getText().toString());`

Comment: @Redman `getText()` on an `EditText` will not return a null, atleast in my experience it never did.

Comment: then may be he can also check for empty text with and condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to make sure that the input to the "parseDouble" is valid:

```
    double totalTips = 0;
    Editable totalString = totalTipsInput.getText();
    if(totalString.length() > 0){
        totalTips = Double.parseDouble(totalString.toString());
    }
```

If the "totalTips" field can take user input you need to make sure they can only enter a valid number. The lazy way might be to put a try/catch around the parseDouble as well, and handle the case where someone may enter something that can't be parsed to a double (ie, empty string, letters, malformed numerical value)

I would recommend not trusting users to always input valid values in the rest of the waiter hours fields as well. You would want to do similar checks on those fields before attempting to parse the input.

Comment: thanks that worked!

Comment: good. @Kiskae, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method in your class:

```
 public static Double returnDouble(EditText editText)
    {
        try {
            if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                return 0d;
            }
            else
            {
                return Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            return 0d;
        }

    }
```